# Obtain primes with threads. How to divide intervals?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, primes, divide

I want to obtain all the prime numbers in the interval `[min, max]`. I want to do the calculus in `n` servers. Which is the best way to divide my initial interval in another `n` intervals, to manage approximately the same load in all the `n` servers?

---

[Optional]

---

I had an idea, but it didnt work as I expected. I assumed that all numbers are primes, so that a number `i` costs `i` instructions to verify is a prime.

If we keep in mind this method:

[image]

Then, the number of instructions to get primes in interval [1,100] is `1+2+..+99+100 = 100(1+100)/2 = 5050`.

Now, if I want to do this calculus in 2 servers (`n=2`), I have to divide this load to each one (2525 instructions each one). The interval I want is defined by `2525 = x(1+x)/2 -> x=71`.

In general terms, the general formula would be `Load = (Interval(x) - Interval(x-1) + 1) * (Interval(x-1) + Interval(x)) / 2`, being `Load = (max - min + 1) * (min + max) / (2 * n)`.

Doing this, with `x and y = [1:9999999]` and `n = 16`, I have got this results:

[image]
<sub>(source: [subirimagenes.com](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_948211012c6a4f9423d5b03819d.png))</sub>

I dont get the same time and instructions in all servers, what means this is not the way to divide the intervals.

Any idea?

Comment: isn't that more of a math than programming question?

Comment: Yes it is. Still knowledge and curiosity :D

Comment: Besides that this is purely mathematical (and there might be better sites to ask such questions) ... I have some gut feeling that your base assumption will not work: you can not assume that prime numbers are evenly distributed. Bigger numbers are less likely prime numbers than smaller likes. So, when you just create intervals of same size, they will contain (significantly?!) different  counts of primes.

Comment: there is http://math.stackexchange.com/ for those kind of questions :) There are also nice algorithms like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes and there is math for that on wp

Comment: @Jägermeister Yes you have right, that's the reason I have not created intervals of same size. My first intervals are bigger because of you say, and a `i` number will not cost `i` instructions (for example, even numbers will only cost 1 instruction).

Comment: @zapl Thanks for that info, didn't know that web page. I will try to solve it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for a parallel approach.
This is what the [work stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) algorithm was designed for, aka [Fork Join Pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). In fact, prime number calculation is a classic use case for work stealing because telling whether `n` is prime requires iterating till `sqrt(n)` so the bigger is n the longer it takes. So distributing them among your workers evenly and waiting for every worker to finish its job is unfair, the first core will quickly determine whether n is prime or not and sit idle and the other core will stay busy calculating bigger numbers. With work stealing the idle processor will steal work from its neighbours queues.

[This implementation might be useful.](https://github.com/accso/fork-join-demo/blob/master/fork-join-demo/src/de/accso/testbed/forkjoin/primes/ParallelPrimeWorker.java)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I didn't do a first complete division of my interval and assign each part to a different server. I made the decision to divide the interval into very small parts (`[min, max]/length^2` for example), and each calculus server got one of these parts. When they finish, they get another one until there is no more small intervals to calculate.

Why did I do this? The reason it's because I can't ensure that the servers I'm working with have the same calculus speed.